# jquery ajax progress bar с циклом в php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xhr

Всем привет! Пытаюсь использовать jQuery AJAX для моих целей, но столкнулся с проблемой:

```js
$('#go').on('click',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $('#progress-bar').show();

    console.log('starting ajax request');
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width', '' + (100 * e.loaded / e.total) + '%');
                }
            });
            return xhr;
        },

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'core.php',
        data: {},
        complete: function (response, status, xhr) {
            console.log(response);
            $('.desc').html(response.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
 padding-top: 20px;
}
#progress-bar {
 margin-top: 20px;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="btn btn-default" id="go">Let's go!</a>
  <div class="progress" id="progress-bar">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">

  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В **core.php** мне нужно провести будет некоторые операции над массивами. Предположим, это будет:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<9999; $i++) {
    $sum++;
}
?>
```

Мой javascript не работает. Знаю, что это из-за того, что **e.lengthComputable = false**. Также узнал, что **core.php** headers содержат **Content-Length: 0**. Ок. Но что я должен сделать, чтоб мой AJAX запрос работал верно и работал динамический прогресс бар? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Length: 0`, потому что из PHP нет никакого вывода. 
Поставьте что-то вроде этого:
`echo "прогресс" $progress;`, ну или что там у вас нужно от контроллера вернуть, чтобы в html затем вставить.

В общем, то, что хотите, лучше через websockets сделать, чтобы сам сервер пушал обновления когда у него прогресс, и лучше это делать на node.js.

Есть реализации сокетов и под php, но я, правда, заглянул разок как это сделано там, пришел в ужас и предпочитаю использовать node.js. К тому же, нагружать контроллеры PHP интенсивными вычислениями не рекомендуется наукой - если это скажем магазин, вы его положите рано или поздно, когда даже несколько десятков посетителей запустят нечто подобное. Для серверов с интенсивными вычислениями обычно берут Java EE, ставят большую железку. PHP, да и Node.js, по большому счету, для этого не годится.

Comment: Спасибо!
`<?php

for ($i=0;$i<50; $i++) {
 echo 'Current number is: '.$i.'<br/>';
}

?>`
А как сделать так, чтоб текущее число отображалось по мере загрузки прогресс бара и это всё было завязано?

Comment: расширил ответ. всё время бегать за обновлениями прогресса через ajax как белка в колесе думаю не совсем правильно... хотя если хочется - планируйте ajax-запрос раз в 10-30 сек через setInterval, не забудьте потом это периодическое задание снять когда процесс закончится

Comment: также у вас цикл обработки не должен запускаться в точке получения прогресса. вы должны запустить процесс расчета в отдельной точке входа, периодически сохранять прогресс в переменной сессии, а запрос на получение прогресса должен только взять переменную сессии  и вернуть ее, всё

Comment: запрос, который инициировал расчет, будет при этом висеть и ждать ответа, пока апач не убьет его по таймауту вместе с вашим циклом :-)) короче, ложитесь спать а завтра (или в понедельник) подумайте как всё это сделать правильно :-)